# How can I take away RAM from a running Kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I've got pods that use a greatly varying amount of memory over their lifetime.

If I understand correctly, in K8S, if a pod gets more memory (growing from request to limit), it doesn't relinquish it back to the common pool, even after it no longer needs it.

So I ended up in a situation where I've got many pods, all of which have lots of RAM that they don't need for 95% of their lifetime.

So, is there any way to get memory back from greedy pods when they're inactive? Without killing them I mean, as that would present its own complications.